# How to convert ajax request to unobtrusive javascript?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an ajax code:

```
$('select#books_order').on('change', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/books/#{@book.id}",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'script',
    data: {
     sort: $('#books_order option:selected').val()
    }
  });
});
```

which can be interpreted into something like this

```
select#books_order data-remote="true" data-url="/books/#{@book.id}" data-method="get"
  option value='desc' Descending
  option value='asc' Ascending
```

However, I have no idea how it is possible to pass **sort** parameter to an action. In the first example I'm just using JQuery to fetch selected option, however my second example sends a request without the parameter.

Comment: Does slim actually have anything to do with this?

Comment: @cale_b I used it for the sake of understanding

Comment: You could just move your JavaScript to your `assets` and pass the `book_id` to it with a `data` attribute (http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast)

Comment: Try adding `.js` ind the end of the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a url parameter to `data-url`.

```
select#books_order data-remote="true" data-url="/books/#{@book.id}?sort=desc" data-method="get"
```

Or you could make a hidden form and submit it on change, this would submit the form/action with the sort parameter via ujs.

JS:

```
$('#books_order').on("change blur", function() {
  // Submit form
  $(this).trigger('submit.rails');
});
```

In your view/form:

```
<%= form_tag book_path(@book) do %>
  <%= select_tag :sort, options_for_select([['Descending', 'desc'], ['Ascending', 'asc']])
<% end %>
```

In your controller:

```
params[:sort]
```